# How to perform email validation with Google Forms pre-submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am autogenerating some Google Forms which have the automatic email collection field enabled. I would like to make it so that each of them can only be submitted by certain emails. As such, I would like to check that the auto-collected email is an allowed email address before they submit the Form.

I would prefer not to use a regular textbox that says "enter email here", because then any user who opens the form could input an email which may not be their own.

I know I can check the email is correct after the Form is submitted, but I would prefer to do it before.

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot do it BEFORE the form is submitted, but onFormSubmit you can redirect the user dynamically to a page that informs him about either acceptance or rejection - depending on the outcome of a posterior validation.

Comment: Could I then immediately delete that entry or force the user to go back and edit it before the data gets collected?

Comment: Apps Script features the `onFormSubmit` trigger that allows you to delete the submitted information from the destination spreadsheet  immediately after submit, e.g. with [deleteResponse(responseId)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteresponseresponseid), however it will not remove the response from the form summary.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it seems there is no way to validate automatically collected email before form submission.